# Using the objects retrieved at the time of request validation

Tags: object-oriented, php, validation, code-reuse, laravel

I hope the question title already answers the subject here. Lets say I have a number of ids that needs to be validated in a request.

Example:

**request uri:** 
[POST] `/album/{album_id}/song`

**Request payload:**

```
[
  "song_title": "hello world",
  "genre_id": 2,
  "artist_id": [100, 102],
  "lyrics_by_id": 201
]
```

Now, as we know we would definitely have to validate those ids, for which we run some queries over there.

Is there a way out, where we can use those objects or data retrieved from database in order to use it in the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by doing it in this way. Don't know if it is a best practice or not.

**Merging it as a request payload, in the middleware if required in a lot of places. May be it could have been done in the service provider.**

Example (In Laravel):

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){

    $genre = Genre::findOrFail($request->get('genre_id');
    $request->add('genre', $genre);

    return $next($request);

}
```

Comment: The PSR-7 (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/) defines the `ServerRequestInterface` which has a `withAttribute($name, $value)` method. There it is mentioned that "The request attributes may be used to allow injection of any parameters derived from the request". You can use a middleware that retrieves the objects from the database and add them to the requests attributes. I wouldn't do that in a service provider since they are used to register services to your application and not to transform/process data on every request.